# Using .env Variables with Ghost CMS

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, ghost-blog, env, ghost

I'm trying to use an .env variable for my Ghost application, but I'm running into an issue where my .env file isn't being recognized by my config.js file. I tried setting up my .env file like so:

`.env`:

```
NODE_ENV=development
NODE_ENV=production
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=accesskey
AWS_SECRET_KEY=secretkey
```

and then setting it like so in `config.js`:

```
active: 'ghost-s3',
        'ghost-s3': {
         accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
         secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY,
         bucket: 'blog',
         region: 'us-east-1',
         assetHost: '//s3.amazonaws.com/blog/'
        }
```

but that didn't work. Is there a way to do this using `FS.readSync` or maybe the `foreman` module?

Comment: What makes you assume that the `.env` file is picked up and your env vars are set as per that file? Do you use something like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10908149)

Comment: @Gothdo i still think this was the answer to the question.

Comment: Maybe, but this is certainly not a full answer. Please expand it - add some explanation, refer to docs.